# How to enable Fire and Forget/Asynchronous pattern on Logic App HTTP Trigger/Action?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure logic app that just calls an HTTP endpoint, I don't want to wait for a response as this is triggering a long-running task.

But currently, it waits for the response and fails with a timeout error.

How can I fire and forget the endpoint ( and still have logic app status successful)?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control of the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, The logic app is triggering my own web app's endpoint, at the scheduled time.

Comment: You could use a webhook, have a look at that functionality. It’s not set and forget but it won’t timeout. It will continue after you feedback to the webhook.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Logic App behavior **Asynchronous** or **Fire and Forget** by enabling **Asynchronous Response** setting on the Response action.

[Microsoft Documentation - Handle incoming or inbound HTTPS requests sent to workflows in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption)

[image: HTTP_Response]

[image: HTTP_Response_Setting]

**UPDATE 1**

By default, HTTP action is synchronous, you can enable [Asynchronous request-response behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#asynchronous-request-response-behavior) if that's supported.

Synchronous HTTP request has timeout limit - [HTTP request limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#http-request-limits)

If the above is not helpful then you have to change your web app to respond faster or make it asynchronous

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Should I add a new Response action after the HTTP action? 
Currently, I only have a Recurrence trigger and an  HTTP action

Comment: Looks like the above answer is for incoming HTTP requests to logic app. In my case logic app is making an HTTP call and I don't want to wait for a response.

Comment: @Vish did you ever solve that problem?

Comment: @xr280xr No, in my case, it was appropriate to change the web app (the http endpoint I was calling from logic app) to run the task in background and return the response immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Event grid Trigger and webhook to get long running process response as below:

[image]

As event trigger has a [retry policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule)

Where it first waits for 10 sec response, then 30 sec then 1min until 24 hrs time and we can also set the retry policy too.

Another way is to on asynchronous response to get 202 Response.

[Webhook Event Delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery).